# Como referenciar correctamente charset=utf8

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, codificación

Tengo mi codificación en mi código php en la conexión PDO, funciona correctamente, pero cuando inserta los datos a MySQL las tildes que son; (Ñ) las manda en minúscula ejemplo CASTAñEDA, en mi formulario en la mayoría de los campos, tengo lo que es $strtoupper pero pongo todas en minúscula y todas las convierte a mayúscula menos las tildes que menciono, se que al parecer las mayúsculas, algunas personas manifiestan que no van con acento pero por ejemplo pongo un carácter así ->( Á,Ó) y de igual manera las convierte en la base en (á,ó) ejemplo (Canción) no se cual sea mi error estoy investigando sobre $mb_strtoupper pero en realidad necesito un ejemplo en codificación.

Este es mi código,  en MySQL cree la tabla con utf8_general_ci

```
<?php

$errores = NULL;
$enviado = FALSE;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$nombre =(empty(trim($_POST['nombre'])))  ? NULL :  strtoupper($_POST['nombre']);
$apellidopaterno = (empty(trim($_POST['apellidopaterno']))) ? NULL :  strtoupper($_POST['apellidopaterno']);
$apellidomaterno = (empty(trim($_POST['apellidomaterno']))) ? NULL :  strtoupper($_POST['apellidomaterno']);
$telefono = (empty(trim($_POST['telefono']))) ? NULL :   $_POST['telefono'];
$correo = (empty(trim($_POST['correo']))) ? NULL : $_POST['correo'];
$mensaje = (empty(trim($_POST['mensaje']))) ? NULL :  strtoupper($_POST['mensaje']);

 try{
                                  //codificación
    $conexion = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pruebas;charset=utf8', 'root', '');

}catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo    "Error:" . $e->getMessage();
}

try{

    if (!$nombre){
        $errores .= 'Por favor ingresa tu nombre <br />';
    }

    if (!$apellidopaterno){
        $errores .= 'Por favor ingresa tu apellido paterno <br />';
    }

    if (!$apellidomaterno){
        $errores .= 'Por favor ingresa tu apellido materno <br />';
    }

    if (!$telefono){
        $errores .= 'Por favor ingresa tu teléfono <br />';
    }

    if (!$correo){
        $errores .= 'Por favor ingresa tu correo <br />';
    }

    if (!$mensaje){
        $errores .= 'Por favor ingresa un mensaje <br />';
    }

    if (!$errores){

        $statement = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO usuario(nombre,apellidopaterno,apellidomaterno,telefono,correo,mensaje)VALUES( :nombre, :apellidopaterno,:apellidomaterno, :telefono, :correo, :mensaje)");
        $statement->bindParam(':nombre', $nombre);
        $statement->bindParam(':apellidopaterno', $apellidopaterno);
        $statement->bindParam(':apellidomaterno', $apellidomaterno);
        $statement->bindParam(':telefono', $telefono);
        $statement->bindParam(':correo', $correo);
        $statement->bindParam(':mensaje', $mensaje);
        $conexion->beginTransaction();
        $statement->execute();
        $conexion->commit();
        $enviado=TRUE;
    }

}catch(Exception $e) {
    $conexion->rollback();
    echo "Error: 0" . $e->getMessage();
}


}

require 'index.view.php';



?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa `mb_strtoupper()` en lugar de `strtoupper()`, ya que este método toma en cuenta la codificación

`$str = mb_strtolower($_POST['nombre'], 'UTF-8');`

Inclusive si ya has configurado la codificación, lo puedes omitir, como especifica la documentación

> El parámetro encoding es la codificación de caracteres. Si es omitido, será usado el valor de la codificación de caracteres interna.

Mas información de mb_strtoupper:
http://php.net/manual/es/function.mb-strtoupper.php